# Link prediction for isolated node in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, prediction

I have modeled an operational process as a directed probabilistic graph, in which I can manage to find the best path.
I would like to introduce new nodes, and evaluate if the paths will change, but these nodes are not connected to any of the nodes of my initial graph (isolated nodes). Therefore I have the feeling that I cannot use classic link prediction methods, such as those existing in NetworkX for instance.
In the scientific literature, this problem seems to be referred as "cold start link prediction" or "link prediction in sparse networks" but I am not sure that these methods are well adapted to my problem. I am also wondering whether I should not try supervised learning with training on existing path.
Is there anybody that could help me with that, with any tip on the method or existing library?

To sum up, I have:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=0.6)
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=0.4)
G.add_node(4)
G.has_edge(1,4)
```

which returns false and I would like a function:

```
G.has_potential_edge(1,4)
```

that would return True if the object behind the node 4 has similar features with object 2 or 3, or if we know that the type of transition between 1 and 4 looks like an existing link, based on features of objects 1 and 4.
Any idea of an existing method/algorithm combining graph link prediction and machine learning method?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I might not be following, but why might `G.has_potential_edge(1,4)` return `True`? There is no evident link between nodes `1` and `4`. 


Hence, are you looking for the logic such that: G.has_potential_edge(A,B) => True when both A and B exist in G and there is no explicit rule saying that they could not be linked?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. In fact I had in mind that I could deduce this link by finding a similarity between node 4 and node 3 for instance, or an equivalent transition (to path 1-4) in the graph. This implies the knowledge of features for each of these nodes. That's why I was thinking about applying some Machine Learning method directly to the graph structure. Is that clearer?

Comment: I think I understand! You are saying `G.has_potential_edge(1,4) => True` because `2` or `3` is potentially `4`?

Comment: Let's say 4 "looks like" 2 or 3, which could be inferred by nodes' features.

Comment: When you add an edge, is it one way? I.e. is there an edge from `2-->1` ?

Comment: Can you update your question with example answers please?
e.g. `G.has_potential_edge(1,4) => True` `G.has_potential_edge(1,5) => False`. So that I can get an idea of edges cases and how the relationship works with `2` and `3`?

Comment: I have edited my question to be more precise. G.has_potential_edge(1,5) => False would mean that the transition between node 1 and 5 cannot be inferred from the analysis of the similarity of object/node 5 with nodes connected to 1, and that the transition between objects 1 and 5 seems different from usual transitions in the initial graph. Hope this helps and thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm really sorry, this requires more work than I have time for. However I've found a nice link on it. Hope this helps: 

http://be.amazd.com/link-prediction/

Comment: You may want to put your question on here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/
They are solely for machine learning. :)